# Change in some character encoding when reding a MS word file using python docx module and saving it back

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I am reading a word file (word file is just having a huge table), inserting a blank row after each row in the table and saving it back. After save, the new file is having some characters changed. I am guessing change in the encoding is happening.

Here is my code for reading and saving it.

```
def insert_row_in_table(table):
    empty_row = get_empty_row(table) # this function will return an empty row
    for row in table.rows:
        tr = row._tr
        tr.addnext(copy.deepcopy(empty_row))


def convert(file: str):
    doc = docx.Document(file)
    row_c = 0
    for table in doc.tables:
        insert_row_in_table(table)

    # save file
    file_name = os.path.splitext(file)
    new_name = file_name[0] + '_updated' + file_name[1]
    doc.save(new_name)
```

This is how its looking when i am comparing both the files (Left side: Original file, Right side: Updated file)
[image]

How to preserve the characters encoding or avoid this issue?

Comment: What you get out is the UTF8 representation of the original characters. Check your output encoding.

Comment: @usr2564301 Is there any way to specify the encoding when saving the file? I am not able to find any save() method which takes encoding as argument.